# include duplicates when using WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql

I have tho following MySQL query:

```
$sql = ' SELECT tableA.id, tableA.title 
        FROM  tableA
        JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.land_id 
        WHERE tableB.id IN ('.$idlist.')';
```

Problem is I need to also include duplicates from the $idlist. `WHERE IN` returns only unique matches of the `$idlist`.
So each variable in the idlist needs to return a matching id and title from the `tableA`.

Comment: what does $idlist contain? (is it a string with multiple ids seperated by `,` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

A `WHERE` condition evaluates each record against the condition. It goes through the data in the database and asks for each row *"is this record `IN (...)`?"*. It then only returns the records which match that *filter*. You could easily post-process the returned data in PHP and duplicate whatever you need to duplicate, this would be the most efficient way. The database doesn't have to return the same data twice, you can duplicate the data yourself in PHP if necessary.

If you need the database to return duplicate rows, you pretty much have to concatenate individual queries into a recordset yourself. Instead of one `` ... WHERE `foo` IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a') `` query, you need to issue several unioned queries:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo = 'a'
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE foo = 'b'
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE foo = 'c'
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE foo = 'a'
```

Comment: Why should one load a record with `foo = 'a'` twice? If this record is in the result once, you could read it from there as often as you want. The Records should be identical, as the WHERE clause is identical. As far as I understood this you are just loading unnecessary data.

Comment: Notice that I'm saying exactly that very verbosely in the first paragraph.

Comment: Ok, but the idlist could be up to 150 rows, won't this slow down the query heaps. I hav enow solved it temporarily by looping through a query. However this of course ends up running a query for each item which could then end up being up to 150 queries.

Not sure what you mean with post process the data.